Measuring distance from house to Natural Park
We have built a house and are being prosecuted for building within 2km of a natural park.
How do I check?

Walking the distance with a handheld GPS would give you that answer quickly.

You need the location of the house and the boundary of the park. Do you have these? If not then your Q needs to be "How do I find the location of my house?" and another Q for "How do I find the boundary of XYZ Natural Park?". Then its a standard GIS operation to get the nearest distance.

To get a rough estimate, you can measure the distance from your property to the borders of the national park. Go to Google Maps right click on a point select 'Measure Distance' and then select a second point.
A safer option would be to do an analysis in ArcGIS/QGIS using data from a geospatial survey (your house, national park) from an official institution (government, your contractor, ...).
